# Skip Parity interactive password for signer

Tags: parity

Is there a way to skip password/confirm at every transaction in parity? This would be really useful to work with dev chain and make multiple test quickly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Run parity with

```
parity --chain dev --fast-unlock --unlock "0xdead,0xbeef,..." --password /path/to/password.txt
```

This will automatically unlock your account(s) with the provided passwords. Note, don't use this in production ;)

```
--fast-unlock
    Use drasticly faster unlocking mode. This setting causes raw secrets to be stored unprotected in memory, so use with care.
--unlock=[ACCOUNTS]
    Unlock ACCOUNTS for the duration of the execution. ACCOUNTS is a comma-delimited list of addresses. Implies --no-ui.
--password=[FILE]...
    Provide a file containing a password for unlocking an account. Leading and trailing whitespace is trimmed. (default: [])
```